# HTML Range Input Sliders disappear on mobile. Why?

Tags: html, forms, css

Why do HTML5 inputs of type range disappear on mobile?  See [this](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php) page, inspect as a mobile device.  I'm working on a simple site with a form but need the form to work on mobile.  Thanks!

Comment: You might want to tell us in which browser you did the emulation. I guess Chrome? I works for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Range inputs do work properly on mobile (see [Can I use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=range%20input%20type)).

In your example ([Link](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-range.php)) it seems like a simulation issue of Google Chrome. If you test your link via Firefox or on a mobile device with Safari or Google Chrome the sliders work fine.

Comment: This is correct, the sliders disappear in the chrome mobile emulator but do indeed show on real mobile devices.  Thank you!

Comment: Just ran into this myself. Oddly enough, you can still use the control by dragging your mouse over it, it's just invisible. Also: it *does* show up if you override the CSS for `input[type="range"]` and its various pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 4):

It is compatible (if you believe caniuse):
http://caniuse.com/#search=range%20input%20type

It should work.

Comment: You can use it in Chrome but it does not work in the emulator